# Third Degree Polynomial

Tags: polynomials

Given $f(x)=a*x^{3}+b*x^{2}+c*x+10 $ and that $f(20)=0, f'(20)=0, f'(0)=0$
find the coefficients a, b, and c. I already figured out that $c=0$ because if the derivative of $f(x)$ is $f'(x) = 3*ax^{2}+2bx+c$ then $f'(0)=c$ and since $f'(0)=0, c=0$

I know that the answer is $a=\frac{20}{8000}$ and $b=\frac{20}{400}+\frac{10}{400}$ I just don't know how to get there

Comment: It would improve the Question to explain the reasoning for $c=0$.  High school level problem it may be, but you must at least know the derivative of a polynomial to approach this, and a little about solving simultaneous linear equations (to find $a,b$ once $c=0$ is plugged back in).

Comment: I don't see why you wouldn't think to use the same technique you just used to find a system of two equations that would let you solve for $a$ and $b$.

Comment: What do you mean by, "at least know the derivative of a polynomial"? I know how derivatives work and how to take the derivative of a polynomial, what I fail to see is how solving simultaneous linear equastions is going to help me with a polynomial @hardmath

Comment: Once the function and its (polynomial) derivative are evaluated at the indicated arguments, we get linear equations involving $a,b,c$ as unknowns.  Your discovery that $c=0$ is just such an equation, and it allows to work solely on finding $a,b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also know that

$$0=f'(20)=1200a+40b\Rightarrow b=-30a.$$

We can use this with the original polynomial to get

$$0=f(20)=10-4000a\Rightarrow a=\frac{1}{400}$$

Comment: Honestly, I tried this method several times and got the wrong answer everytime, I guess i just needed to see the correct calculations! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

$f'(x)=3ax^2+2bx+c$ has roots $0$ and $20$. Therefore $$3ax^2+2bx+c=3ax(x-20)=3ax^2-60ax.$$
Then $b=-30a,c=0$ and $f(x)=ax^3-30ax^2+10$.

$0=f(20)=8000a-12000a+10$. Therefore $a=\frac{1}{400}$ and $b=-\frac{30}{400}.$